# MySQL - how to execute LARGE querys?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In Workbench, I export my entire DB design into a series of CREATE TABLE statements. I was running into errors due to the size query (there are over 50 tables). Is there something I can do to make MySQL accept large queries?

Also, I have a big SQL to insert dummy data. I assume I'll run into the same problem as well.

The SQL queries are in a file. I want to programatically open the file, grab the query, then execute it. I'm using PHP/CodeIgniter.

Comment: What errors ? I have 100's of tables and millions of records - i rarely run in to issues - maybe some settings (timeouts) need to be tweeked but we should get an idea of that from the errors

Comment: Including your SQL would be good too ....

Comment: You can export your 100s of tables into CREATE TABLE statements, then programatically execute it all in one go?

Comment: They dont execute in parellel - but yes ...

Comment: I must have done something wrong, then. I ended up having to open the file, then break the queries into smaller chunks, then running the chunks one at a time.

Comment: What errors are you getting ? it might just be a simple timeout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple queries by using the mysql commandline client and reading them from file or STDIN. That normally works without any issues and I know a lot of systems that rely on this.

Please see [4.5.1. `mysql` — The MySQL Command-Line Tool<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) and *non-interactive* use.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues like this before on shared hosting and on poorly performing local machines.

I have used [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) in the past to stagger the import.

Breaking up the import isn't always an option if someone has given you a dump file, exporting it differently isn't an option as you may not have access to the original DB.